# How to handle answers to this question?

Tags: discussion

How would you suggest I handle the answers to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2194)?

I want to give credit to both answers, because they both gave me good information to dig further (one to a post on the same issue on a Google Group, one with a link to the Known Issues site). I've voted them both up, but which one should I mark as "correct"? Technically, none of them really *solved* my issue, but rather provided a bit of information surrounding it.

Perhaps this is a sign of a bad question to start with?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My point of view would be that the answer (which now has the most votes) regarding the patch would be the 'correct' answer as it explains what the resolution will be, even if the resolution is not something you can effect yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I would still accept the person to first point you at this being a bug/issue as the answer to your question.  You were unable to do something and wanted to know why, which was answered right ? 
Having the question stay open, without an accepted answer isn't positive for the content of the website or your acceptance rate.